# Lync Client SDK - Consultative Transfer - Retrieve original call if 3rd party ignore Ignores the call

Tags: lync, lync-client-sdk

I am developing an extension on top of Lync using Client SDK.

In one case, I receive a call from Party A. I want to do a consultative transfer to Party B. Once Party B replies, I do the consultative transfer from Party A to B.

All the above works fine. Except for one case, when Party B declines or ignores the call.

In such a situation, I hear the voice message and I cannot retrieve back the call with Party A.

So my question is, once Party B ignores or declines the call, how can I retrieve the call with Party A instead of hearing that voice message coming from Party B?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1):

The setup is a client setup for Party B.  This is only the default behavior when you have voicemail setup in Skype.  This can be changed manually in Party B's Skype client.

From the Lync SDK you can't do what you want to do, to achieve what you want you will have to either use your add-on with a UCMA trusted application and/or Lync Server MSPL / Proxy application.

I would go the UCMA trusted application route.  What you can do is get a trusted application to do the dialing for you of Party B for you and then stay in the sip path or drop out.

Follow this [blog article](http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/12/28/prevent-lync-calls-voice-mail/) to disable forwarding.  (Note: this disables  Forwarding in general, you may like to use the linked article about detecting a voicemail answered call instead).

You can either setup the call as a B2BCall or once answered you can transfer the call back to Lync Client.